# ¿Como hacer la siguiente consulta SQL?

Tags: sql

Hola comienzo a trabajar con SQL, les agradecería me ayudaran ya que se me dificulta hacer la siguiente consulta, no se como hacerla

```
TABLE employees 
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
managerId INTEGER REFERENCES employees(id) 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

**¿como puedo hacer una consulta que seleccione los nombres de empleados que no son managers?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Un simple `NOT EXISTS` debería ser suficiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees AS e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Employees
                 WHERE managerId = e.Id);
```